# Python threading module import failure

Tags: python, multithreading, import

I'm trying to import the threading module, however, i just seem to get errors for no good reason. Here is my code:

```
import threading

class TheThread ( threading.Thread ):
    def run ( self ):
        print 'Insert some thread stuff here.'
        print 'I\'ll be executed...yeah....'
        print 'There\'s not much to it.'

TheThread.Start()
```

And the errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "threading.py", line 1, in <module>
    import threading
  File "C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Scripting\Python\Threading\threading.py", line
3, in <module>
    class TheThread ( threading.Thread ):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Thread'
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Python stats:

> Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit
>   (Intel)] on win 32

Comment: Do you have file named "threading.py" in your current directory? If so, this would probably be the cause of there being no Thread attribute.

Comment: Remember to delete `threading.pyc` if you have run the code before

Answer (score 57, accepted):

i think that all you need is just to rename the name of your working file, because your file name is the same as module name:

> threading.py

or you have wrong threading.py file in your working directory

Comment: I'm confused as to why this answer didn't exist when I left my comment above. Anyway, you beat me to it.

Comment: silly me not to noteice that the file was same name as module :/

Comment: Tyler, i answered, then temporary deleted answer to simulate this situation on my computer:)

Answer (score 4):

First, you have to rename your own file: It is called threading.py and since it is in the Python Path it replaces the threading module of the standard Python library.

Second, you have to create an instance of your thread-class:

```
TheThread().start() # start with latter case
```

Answer (score 0):

_thread.start_new_thread(func*)

Comment: this is the new syntax for python 3

Answer (score 0):

I think you used threading name to your current working file.Change your file name with different name.It will work.It works for me too